# Can gRPC server reclaim the DEADLINE_EXCEEDED thread immediately?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, grpc, grpc-java

Is it right to say that - java gRPC server thread will still run even after the DEADLINE time.  But, gRPC server will stop/block that thread only from making any subsequent gRPC calls since the DEADLINE time has crossed?

If the above is a correct statement, then is there a way to stop / block the thread making any Redis / DB calls as well for which DEADLINE time has crossed ?  Or once the DEADLINE time is crossed, interrupt the thread immedietly?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it right to say that - java gRPC server thread will still run even after the DEADLINE time.

Correct. Java doesn't offer any real alternatives.

> But, gRPC server will stop/block that thread only from making any subsequent gRPC calls since the DEADLINE time has crossed?

Mostly. Outgoing gRPC calls observe the `io.grpc.Context`, which means deadlines and cancellations are propagated (unless you fail to propagate Context to another thread or use `Context.fork()`).

> If the above is a correct statement, then is there a way to stop / block the thread making any Redis / DB calls as well for which DEADLINE time has crossed ? Or once the DEADLINE time is crossed, interrupt the thread immedietly?

You can listen for the Context cancellation via `Context.addListener()`. The gRPC server will cancel the Context when the deadline expires and if the client cancels the RPC. This notification is how outgoing RPCs are cancelled.

I will note that thread interruption is a bit involved to perform without racing. If you want interruption and don't have a `Future` already, I suggest wrapping your work in a `FutureTask` (and simply calling `FutureTask.run()` on the current thread) in order to get its non-racy `cancel(true)` implementation.

```
final FutureTask<Void> future = new FutureTask<Void>(work, null);
Context current = Context.current();
CancellationListener listener = new CancellationListener() {
  @Override public void cancelled(Context context) {
    future.cancel(true);
  }
};
current.addListener(listener);
future.run();
current.removeListener(listener);
```

Comment: is this still the same case for Java?

Comment: It is still valid. Although it is specific to _thread interruption_. Cancellation in general has other options, like `ServerCallStreamObserver.setOnCancelHandler()`.

Comment: thank you. Can you point me to an example setup where I can expect server to cancel the work (at hand) when client's deadline exceeds. And client ofcourse gets deadline-exceeded error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`Context.isCancelled()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Context.html) before making Redis / DB queries, and throw [`StatusException(CANCELLED)`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/StatusException.html#StatusException-io.grpc.Status-) if it has.